# Integer.MIN_VALUE divide by -1

Tags: java, integer-overflow

## why this line of code matters?(I get a wrong answer without it)

```
if (dividend == Integer.MIN_VALUE && divisor == -1) {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

## The question:

Divide two integers without using multiplication, division and mod operator.

If it is overflow, return 2147483647

## Answer

```
public int divide(int dividend, int divisor) {

    if(divisor == 0){
        return dividend > 0 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    if(dividend == 0){
        return 0;
    }

    if (dividend == Integer.MIN_VALUE && divisor == -1) {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    boolean isNeg = (dividend > 0 && divisor < 0) || (dividend < 0 && divisor > 0);


    Long up = Math.abs((long) dividend);
    Long down = Math.abs((long) divisor);

    int res = 0;

    while(up >= down){
        int shift = 0;

        while(up >= (down << shift)){
            shift++;
        }

        up -= down << (shift - 1);
        res += 1 << (shift - 1);
    }

    return isNeg ? -res : res;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java use 32 bit to store `int`.

The max int value is 2<sup>31</sup>-1

```
0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

The min int value is -2<sup>31</sup>

```
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

In other words, int does not have a big enough value to store 2<sup>31</sup>(`-Integer.MIN_VALUE`).

Answer (score 8):

Because, the absolute values of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE` are not equal.

- `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647`
- `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is `-2147483648`

In case you divide `Integer.MIN_VALUE` by `-1`, the value would overflow (`2147483648 > 2147483647`), thus there must be a limit for this operation.